# How to create diagram from a composable function in jetpack compose?

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I am working on Frontends using Kotlin and Jetpack compose in Android Studio.
I have created a Kotlin-File that contains a composable function and no attributes.
I was thinking of a class diagram, but the file has no attributes, only a function.
How can I draw a diagram that represents this file and its composable function?
Which diagram should I choose?

Comment: you mean you're using [Compose for Web](https://compose-web.ui.pages.jetbrains.team)?

Comment: no, i am using jetpack compose to build UI in Android Studio, it is an App